# How to use modules in Opa?

Tags: function, module, call, opa

OK, this is pretty basic question, but I cannot figure this out... What is the correct way to call functions from modules? The way I do it is:

main.opa:

```
function start(){
    Page.page();
}

Server.start(
    Server.http, 
    [
        {title: "Calculator", page: start}
    ]
);
```

Where in the other, page.opa file I have:

```
module Page {
    function page(){
         <p>Consider this as html block...</p>
    }
}
```

Now, the error I get is that Page variable is unbound (it's not a variable at all!). Both files are in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

How you compile your application? The following command should well works

```
opa page.opa main.opa
```

Then run the produced JavaScript file as an executable

```
./main.js
```

Or use the "--" option of the Opa compiler to compile and run

```
opa page.opa main.opa --
```